# Polymer : Hide menu on login page

Tags: polymer, drawer

I'm new to polymer. I want to hide sidebar menu in login page. I have function `IsLoggedIn`, it return true or false. how can I implement it?
this is my code

```
<app-drawer-layout fullbleed narrow="{{narrow}}">
  <!-- Drawer content -->
  <app-drawer id="drawer" slot="drawer" swipe-open="[[narrow]]">
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="home-quotes" href="[[rootPath]]home-quotes">Home</a>
      <a name="secret-quotes" href="[[rootPath]]secret-quotes">Secret</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>

  <!-- Main content -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

    <app-header slot="header" condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>My App</div>
        <a name="register-login" href="[[rootPath]]register-login">Login</a>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="view404"
        role="main">
      <home-quotes name="home-quotes"></home-quotes>
      <secret-quotes name="secret-quotes"></secret-quotes>
      <register-login name="register-login"></register-login>
      <not-found name="not-found"></not-found>
    </iron-pages>
  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you mean with the sidebar menu but I assume that you are revering to the drawer.

You could use the hidden property on the app-drawer element.
Store the return value from your function in a property and bind this to the hidden.
In the example below I stripped the code down to the basics to make it more readable.

**The Drawer:**

```
<app-drawer id="drawer" slot="drawer" swipe-open="[[narrow]]" hidden="[[isLoggedIn]]">
   <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
</app-drawer>
```

**The function:**

```
loggedIn: function() {
   //I just assume the user is logged in...
   this.set('isLoggedIn', true);
   // You might have to call resetLayout()
   this.resetLayout();
}
```

Comment: I want full page width in login page. Actually I want to remove menu in login page.

Comment: which menu ? the hidden property will hide the drawer menu. you can use it also on the other menu.

Comment: hidden="[[isLoggedIn]]" hide content only. it's not remove sidebar. blank sidebar is still there.

Comment: you have to force your layout to fullscreen as the drawer was displayed before. I updated my answer not sure if it will work tho. Try calling resetLayout();

Comment: where is `resetLayout()` function?

Comment: @VipulSolanki its a intern function from Polymer.
Can you accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the drawer as `<template is='dom-if' if='{{!isLoggedIn}}'></template>`.

```html
<!--Initiliaze header and menu-->
<app-header id="header" role="navigator" scroll-target="scrollingRegion" elevation="2">
  <app-toolbar spacer class$ ="{{page}}">
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" id="drawer"  on-tap="toggleDrawer" ></paper-icon-button>
    <a href="/"> 
    <paper-button><div main-title style="color:white;">job<span style="color:red;">i</span>Joy</div></paper-button></a>
    <span class="flex"></span>
    <paper-toggle-button id="freeBusy" checked={{udata.isFree}} on-checked-changed = 'busyFreeOptionsHasBeenChanged'  disabled$="{{!signedin}}"></paper-toggle-button >
    <div  style="font-size:10px;" >[[calculateFreeBusy(udata.isFree)]]</div>
    <paper-icon-button  icon="help-outline" on-tap="selectBusyToastWarning" ></paper-icon-button>

    
    
  </app-toolbar> 
  
  <app-toolbar  id="menuSat1" class$ ="{{page}}" >   
      <paper-tabs selected = "{{page}}" attr-for-selected="name">
        <paper-tab name = "wall" link><iron-icon icon="dashboard"></iron-icon><a href="/wall"  ></a></paper-tab>
        <paper-tab name = "list" link><iron-icon icon="card-travel"></iron-icon><a href="/list"></a></paper-tab>
        <paper-tab name = "maps" link><iron-icon icon="maps:map"></iron-icon><a href="/maps"   ></a></paper-tab>
        <paper-tab name = "bcards" link><iron-icon icon="payment"></iron-icon><a href="/bcards"  ></a></paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
  </app-toolbar>
  <paper-progress  indeterminate class="green" disabled="{{progresDisabled}}"></paper-progress>
</app-header>
 <template is="dom-if" if="{{!signedin}}">
 <app-drawer id="drawer" opened="{{drawerOpened}}" swipe-open  tabindex="0" page="[[page]]">
 
        <jj-drawer
            signedin="{{signedin}}"
            user="{{user}}"
            ltext="{{ltext}}"
            udata="{{udata}}"
            nav-lang="{{navLang}}"
        ></jj-drawer>

  
</app-drawer>
</template>
```

Comment: I believe that the layout is not on narrow so it will show the white space when the drawer is removed.

Comment: What is the error ..? Dom-if is conditional rendering element.

Comment: firstly, I tried like this but it's not working that's why I asked question. :)

Comment: I think i know why. But i will check it at computer first after 2-3 hours.

Comment: I tested at my app and working good (my app code is above snipped code), I tried to illustrate at codepen but I not able yet. For a short result, I wrapped the drawer between `dom-if template`. Be sure that you have pre defined `isLoggedIn` property in `static get properties() { return {` section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167849/discussion-between-vipul-solanki-and-hakanc).

Comment: The OP stated that `ìsLoggedIn` is a function, so it should be `if='[[!isLoggedIn()]]'` (added parenthesis). Also, the dom-if doesn't need to have listeners, so I changed {{ }} to [[ ]].

Answer (score 0):

To completely hide the menu on specific pages of an app, I had to do 2 things:

- hide the `app-drawer` as suggested in the other answers (I chose to set the `hidden` property, but wrapping it in a `dom-if` should work as well)
- additionally, set `force-narrow` ([see docs](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/7102063a78778100ed68e66a43bfcff41cc48577/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html#L193)) on `app-drawer-layout` for those pages to center the page content on screens wider than the responsive width

Example:

```
<app-drawer-layout
    responsive-width="1024px"
    fullbleed
    force-narrow="[[isHidingMenu(page)]]">
  <app-drawer
      slot="drawer"
      hidden$="[[isHidingMenu(page)]]">
    <!-- ... -->
  </app-drawer>
  <!-- ... -->
</app-drawer-layout>
```

You need to add an instance method `isHidingMenu(page)` and return true if the current page should not have a drawer menu.